# The standard p-norm on $L^p$ space is indeed a norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

For $p\ge1$, define $l^p$ as the set of sequences $x=(x_{k})_{k}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lvert x_k\rvert^p<\infty$ and let $$\lVert x\rVert:=(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lvert x_k\rvert^p)^{1/p}$$I want to prove that this is indeed a norm on $l^p$, in particular, I want to prove the definiteness property. I assume the series on the right converges to $0$, so that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lvert x_k\rvert^p=0$. Then ${\forall \varepsilon}  \gt0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge N$ $$\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^p<\varepsilon$$  If $n$ was a fixed natural number and independent of $\varepsilon$, then by analytical properties it would imply that this finite sum is zero, which implies $ \forall k\in\{1,..,n\}, x_k=0$. My problem is to extend this to $\forall k\ge1$. Any ideas?

Comment: $|x_n|^{p} \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k|^{p}$ for each $n$

Comment: If $\sum|x_k|=0$ then *all* elements in the sum have to be zero, no need for epsilons and omikrons.